# QCalendarWidget

Tags: c++, qt

вывод данных mainwindow.cpp

```
model =  new QSqlTableModel(this,baze);
model->setTable("orders");
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
model->select();
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
ui->tableView->hideColumn(0);
ui->tableView->hideColumn(4);

new_o = new newOrder();
new_o->setParent(this,Qt::Window);
new_o->setModel(model);


connect(new_o,SIGNAL(ready()),this,SLOT(orderAccepted()));
```

диалоговое окно по добавлению данных neworder.cpp

```
 mapper = new QDataWidgetMapper(this);
    mapper->setSubmitPolicy(QDataWidgetMapper::ManualSubmit);  
}


void newOrder::setModel(QAbstractItemModel *model)
{
    mapper->setModel(model);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->adressLineEdit,1);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->orderTextEdit,2,"plainText");
    mapper->addMapping(ui->phoneLineEdit,3);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->execDateTimeEdit,5);
}

void newOrder::on_applyButton_clicked()
{ 
    mapper->submit();
    emit ready();
    close();
}
```

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на даты календарика(QCalendarWidget на mainWindow) в таблице выводились данные с соответствующими датами. Текущая дата по дефолту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

мало ли кому из новичков поможет. РЕШЕНИЕ:

```
ваша_модель->setFilter(QString("поле_с_датой = '%1'").arg(QDate::currentDate().toString("yyyy-MM-dd")));//текущая дата
```

чтобы сортировка была по нажатию на даты в календарике:

```
ui->ваш_календарик = new QCalendarWidget();

void MainWindow::on_ваш_календарик_clicked(const QDate &date)
{
     ваша_модель->setFilter(QString("поле_с_датой = '%1'").arg(date.toString("yyyy-MM-dd")));
}
```

поле в базе данных должно быть типа DATE().

Answer (score 0):

У `QCalendarWidget` имеется сигнал `clicked(const QDate &date)` с атрибутом выбранной даты. Похожий сигнал `activated(const QDate &date)` аналогичен, но срабатывает лишь при двойном щелчке кнопки мыши, либо нажатии клавиши <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Как поменять данные в табличном виджете, зависит от наименования и типа поля в таблице БД, но если предположить, что оно носит имя `date` и является строкой, то всё сводится к тривиальной фильтрации:

```
QCalendarWidget *calendar = new QCalendarWidget(this);
connect(calendar, &QCalendarWidget::clicked, [this,model](const QDate &date) {
    model->setFilter("`date`='%1'").arg(date.toString('yyyy-MM-dd'));
});
```

В случае, если модель уже содержала какие-то данные, т.е. ранее уже был выполнен метод `select()`, то в его новом вызове необходимости нет (он будет выполнен прозрачно). Иначе, при первой установке фильтра необходимо его вызвать:

```
QCalendarWidget *calendar = new QCalendarWidget(this);
connect(calendar, &QCalendarWidget::clicked, [this,model](const QDate &date) {
    model->setFilter("`date`='%1'").arg(date.toString('yyyy-MM-dd'));
    if(model->rowCount() == 0) model->select();
});
```

Comment: не сработало ((((   capture of non-variable 'MainWindow::model'
     connect(calendar, &QCalendarWidget::clicked, [this,model](const QDate &date) ну и `invalid use of 'void'
         model->setFilter("`date`='%1'").arg(date.toString('yyyy-MM-dd'));
                                                         ^

Comment: Адаптируйте код под свою реализацию. Копипаст не будет работать.

Comment: я совсем новичок ))) я вот так вот попробовал сделать:                                 ui->calendarWidget = new QCalendarWidget();        void MainWindow::on_calendarWidget_clicked(const QDate &date)
{

   model->setFilter("exec_date=date");
   model->select();

}
как правильно фильтр сделать?